# Openpyxl don't preserve formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file that i want to use as template, what i need is just change the values of some cells, and save it as another excel file. The problem is that when i save it the formatting, style and some date values are changed

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")

ws = wb["RDO"]
ws["B8"].value = "MAI MAN"

wb.save("new.xlsx")
```

The old file:
[image]

The new one:
[image]

As you can see the borders and date fields were changed.

I was thinking in just unzip the excel and modify the xml files, then zip it back, but this approach has a problem. I will need to make a copy of some worksheets, so i tought i should be ok in just copy and paste the sheet.xml file and change the workbook.xml file to add this new sheet, but when i do this all the cells are cleared which is weird because when i copy the sheet in the excel program the output sheet file it's exactly the same as the original

I would like some simple solution if possible, maybe some other library or a fix for this xml sheet problem

Comment: Which version of openpyxl are you using? If you think this is a bug in the library then you should submit a bug report.

Comment: I read that they know about it, but would be difficult to fix it so they didn't. But i will open an issue

Comment: I am using the last one